# Xamarin forms 2.5.0.19271-pre2

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I updated to new version of the xamarin forms, but now the swithes look like this when enabled=false:

[image]

This is a Bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest closing VS, delete all `obj` and `bin` folders in each of the Xamarin projects (shared, Android, iOS, etc.), uninstall the app from the device, and try rebuilding and running everything again.

If it still happens, create a new bug report ([link](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/)).

Comment: Did that, still the same, must be a bug then.